# How to barplot a dataframe, with multiple values for each x value?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot this dataset (fullmala):

```
order_name      CO1    V1    V4    V9
  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Amphipoda      8633    38     6    54
2 Bathynellacea     1     0     0     0
3 Cumacea          97     1     0     0
4 Decapoda      25138     0     0     0
5 Euphausiacea   1627     0     0     0
6 Isopoda        3607   115   106   102
```

What I really wanted was a grouped barplot for each order_name, with 4 Y values for CO1,V1,V4,V9.

I've tried this:

```
color.names = c("black","grey40","grey80","white")
barplot(t(fullmala),beside=T,ylim=c(0,100),xlab="Orders",ylab="Representativeness", col=color.names,axis.lty="solid")
```

But I get an error:
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: Try with `t(fullmala[-1])` - you're including your non-numeric `order_name` column at the moment.

Comment: `barplot(prop.table(as.matrix(fullmala[-1]),2)*100)` or something similar if you want to compare proportions too, which probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting data frame to matrix (leaving out character indicator) and then run `barplot`:

```
mat <- as.matrix(fullmala[2:ncol(fullmala)])
rownames(mat) <- fullmala$order_name

color.names = c("black", "grey40", "grey80", "white")
barplot(mat, beside=TRUE, ylim=c(0,100),
        xlab="Orders", ylab="Representativeness", 
        col=color.names, axis.lty="solid")
```

[image: Plot Output]

Be sure to adjust scales such as with `pretty`: `ylim=range(pretty(c(0, mat)))`.

[image: Y Outlier Plot Output]